# Bootstrap popover only one time for multiple positions

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have a table on my website. I would like to give the user the possibility to easily add comments to each of the row.

For that i found a nice looking comment view on the internet.

here is an example:

```
<div class="popover-markup">
  <a href="#" class="trigger btn btn-default" data-placement="right">Popover link</a>
  <div class="content hide">
    code
  </div>

</div>


$('.popover-markup>.trigger').popover({
  html: true,
  title: function() {
    return $(this).parent().find('.head').html();
  },
  content: function() {
    return $(this).parent().find('.content').html();
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dzr521qs/424/

This is basically exactly what i would like to have. But... I need a form inside of the comment view to post data to my server. And since i have around 50-300 Entries in the table, it would generate a ton of code if i have to place the code for the popover for every single row.

so my question is:

is it possible to define the popover once and show always the same popover but with different content for every row?

I would like to have a small icon on every row whith which i can open the popover and give over an id to the popover to load dynamic content.

hope someone have an idea.

thanks

Comment: Make your fiddle link an actual link versus text and provide the relevant code in the question directly.  ( The fiddle is good to have in addition to code in the question )

Comment: Done... Thank you for your hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add additional attribute to your popover link (say `data-target`) that will point to an element you want to display as content.

You can extract `data` attribute value inside `content()` callback and use it to display different content.

Example:

```
// inside popover(...)
content: function() {
    var contentSelector = $(this).data("target");
    if (contentSelector && $(contentSelector).length > 0) {
        return $(contentSelector).html();
    } else {
        return "<div class='alert alert-warning'>Please specify data-target attribute pointing to element in page</div>";
    }
}

// in your trigger add `data-target` attribute
<a ... data-target=".content">...
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dzr521qs/429/) demonstrating that solution